# My micro SD cards size decreased after making it boot-able?

Tags: usb-drive

I've formated my Frontech 2GB MSD to make it a bootable MSD.Now i've tried to format the MSD but it shows the message  ERROR DELETING  THE PARTITION.
Moreover the 2GB got reduced to 832.5 MB total memory space.

Please help !

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you've done and with which tools? It sort of sounds like you've "burnt" an image to it which has repartitioned it.

Comment: thanks but I've solved it right now .I don't have enough credential to post right now.

Comment: You can answer your own question which will boost your cred in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to display the image.

However,
install  https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-disk-utility/

open disk utility, go to the removable device which is causing the trouble, select the partition unmount the partition with a stop button just below the memory map box.Delete the partition by clicking(-).unmount and delete the other partitions also ,without which the problem mightn't arise. Create a new partiton by clicking (gear) symbol.Select the type of file system you want , in my case its FAT.thats it.

Comment: Upload the image in an image host & post the links here. We'll edit it for you :)

Comment: problem: http://i854.photobucket.com/albums/ab108/thisissaurav/v2_zpsbb92ab8f.jpeg    ------Error faced trying to format without un-mounting the PARTITION:http://i854.photobucket.com/albums/ab108/thisissaurav/v_zpsa5a2e179.jpeg ----- Solution:http://i854.photobucket.com/albums/ab108/thisissaurav/12ca40ce-3f10-45d6-91bc-e74fd49060db_zpsf31ecf3d.jpg